# How to access variables from one method into another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

```
    def check_answer(total,current):
        if user_entry == books:
            current += 1
            total += 1
            currentscore = current


   def __init__(self):
       ...
       self.user_entry = Gtk.Entry()
```

I was wondering how can I access `user_entry` from `__init__` and check it in `check_answer` without getting this error. `NameError: global name 'user_entry' is not defined` This is a GUI if that matters. Also how would I change the Gui for `currentscore` everytime I click the `sumbit`.

```
submit = Gtk.Button("submit")
submit.connect("clicked",self.check_answer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access it on `self`, just like when you set it on the instance in `__init__`:

```
if self.user_entry.get_text() == books:
```

where you get the text out of the `Gtk.Entry()` object by calling the `get_text()` method on it.

Note that your `check_answer` method needs to take a `self` argument for this to work, and must accept the original object as an argument:

```
def check_answer(self, button):
    if self.user_entry.get_text() == books:
        current += 1
        total += 1
        currentscore = current
```

If you need some extra arguments to be passed in, you need to pass these in to `submit.connect()`:

```
submit.connect("clicked", self.check_answer, total, current)
```

but I *suspect* that `total` and `current` and `currentscore` are also attributes on your class.

Perhaps another reading of the [Python tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) would be helpful?

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me the error. File "C:\Python27\guessing.py", line 24, in check_answer
    if self.user_entry == books:
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @ruthless: see the update; you have a method, so it'll need a `self` argument.

Comment: i did what you suggested but i get this error TypeError: check_answer() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @ruthless: You're trying to use `self.check_answer` as a Gtk event handler. This means it will be called with `self, event` as arguments. Just declaring that you want it to get `total, current` or `self, total, current` instead doesn't magically change what Gtk will call it with.

Comment: @ruthless: Right, I am not that familiar with how GTK connections work, but the method is passed just **one** argument when the `submit` Button is clicked. Presumably that is the button object. Where did you get the idea from that `total` and `current` would be passed in?

Comment: @ruthless: Most likely you wanted to access `self.total`, `self.current`, etc., rather than taking them as parameters?

Comment: @ruthless: I did a quick reading of the [PyGtk documentation on the `connect()` method](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gobject.html#method-gobject--connect) and updated the answer. But I sense that you are lacking some basic grounding in Python classes and instances that you'll need to resolve first.